# Finding and replacing(displaying) strings in an array list. What do I add. (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, string, find

I dont know what to add. I need to read texts from an array and find the strings that i would input and replace and display. Thank you. All i have is this program to find the string.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.File;

public class RemoveAndReplace {

static ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    RemoveAndReplace test = new RemoveAndReplace();
    try {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            strings.add(scanner.next());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    //ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<String>(strings);
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("\nPress 1 to remove all occurences of a word \nPress 2 to exit\n:");
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        String command = s.next();

          if (command.equals("1")) {
            test.word();
        } else if (command.equals("2")) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}



public void letter() {

    int let;
    Scanner replaceLetter = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What letter/s would you like to remove?");
    String badLetter = replaceLetter.next();
    replaceLetter.close();

    System.out.print(strings);
}

}
```

Comment: Are you asking for a tip, or complete solution?

Comment: a complete solution will be grea